# which software is used for Windows mobile app devlopment

Tags: sdk, windows

Please give suggestion me which software requirement for developing windows mobile based application?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a number of applications, such as Microsoft's Visual Studio, which is probably a good place to check.

Answer (score 0):

### These are the tools of the trade.

When you install the Windows Phone [SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209107), you get the following free tools and components.

- Expression Blend for Windows Phone
- Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone
- Windows Phone emulator
- XNA Game Studio 4.0
- Silverlight
  -.NET Framework 4

**[Source with a sample app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680270%28v=pandp.11%29.aspx)**